# Error - attribute 'android:appComponentFactory' not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 project and I used this command to build Android platform "cordova platform add Android@6.4.0" using Android Studio 3.1.3 But I have this problem which I don't know how to fix it:

```
error: attribute 'android:appComponentFactory' not found.

Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: attribute
'android:appComponentFactory' not found.,
sources=[C:\Users\Animation\Desktop\ProjectsFile\Attendance
App\attendance\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:41],
original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

So I need help here in order to make this work.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue since yesterday. Please let me know if you find any solution for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by using older version of Android Studio

[android-studio-ide-181.4705630-windows.zip](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.2.0.9/android-studio-ide-181.4705630-windows.zip?hl=zh-TW)

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly faced this issue as well while trying to build even though the project was working fine before.

One of the dependencies had updated over the weekend which caused it to break. Changed my package.json to remove **market** and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this code

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+
```